# A data breach on a site or app exposed your password. Chrome recommends changing your password

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose

I have a `/login` route that gets specific user profile from mongoose. I have `.select('-password')` working which excludes password but I still get the above warning from google chrome.

Comment: This is not a general computing question, it's a dev question! I just got it as well while prototyping an app in create-react-app. I'm not sending anything to any servers at the moment so why is my dev environment, which include chrome, displaying this message? Seems like a fully legit software development message to me.

Comment: Here's [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60470692/why-am-i-getting-a-data-breach-on-a-site-or-app-exposed-your-password-chrome-r), not closed

Answer (score 8):

it is not the issue of node or mongo this feature has been added by google And google chrome for more information please check this like

[warning A data breach on site](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23534509?hl=en&msgid=23692520)

you will get your answer here

Comment: I don't find where to control the feature in Chrome Settings under Sync and Google Services

Comment: HA HA 
Legit message?
A website which was never deployed to public, when start testing this message popup.

a website behind firewall and only from our public IP could be tested!

How could have be hacked?

This is hurting our business!