# Why am I getting "A data breach on a site or app exposed your password. Chrome recommends changing your password on "SITENAME" now."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, google-chrome, axios

I created an app, that stores your password with bcrypt, and the input type of the form is password. I don't understand why I am receiving this alert? Why am I getting "A data breach on a site or app exposed your password. Chrome recommends changing your password on "SITENAME" now."

```
  axios.post(`/signup`, {
                userBody: values.username,
                passwordBody: values.password
            }).then(response => console.log(response))
                .then(response => history.push('/login'))
                .catch(error => {
                    setErrors({
                        error: error.response.status
                    })
                })
        } else {

            alert('cant be empty fields')
        }
    }
```

server.js

app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {

```
const today = new Date();
const userData = {
    username: req.body.userBody,
    password: req.body.passwordBody,
    created: today
};
User.findOne({
    where: {
        username: req.body.userBody
    }
})
    .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.passwordBody, 10, (err, hash) => {
                userData.password = hash
                User.create(userData)
                    .then(user => {
                        res.json({ status: user.username + " registered" })
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        res.send('error' + err)
                    })

            })
        }
        else {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'message' })
            console.log('User exists')
        }

    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send('error' + err)
    })
```

})

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code appears okay. If you are using Google Chrome it has a feature that warns if the password you are using has been previously compromised. So, if you are testing with a common password this may occur. If this is production than you should update your password as the warning indicates.

[Link to Consumer Affairs Article: New version of Chrome warns users if their password was exposed in a data breach](https://www.consumeraffairs.com/news/new-version-of-chrome-warns-users-if-their-password-was-exposed-in-a-data-breach-121119.html)

Comment: thank you i was using abc for pass testing, it freaking me out

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in an app build in react in a development environment in vercel, I solved by changing the password to a more complex and secure one. That is, it has nothing to do with your app

Answer (score 0):

this a new feature from Google Chrome to check password compromised, you can read more about on this Google article: https://security.googleblog.com/2019/12/better-password-protections-in-chrome.html

They also have this Beta API: https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/check-passwords
with that, we can check directly if the user/password is compromised instead to depends on Chrome to inform that as a warning to the users/ customers.

Answer (score 0):

This happens, and while the code may be fine, is better if you take care of it.

I suggest the following three-step process:

1. Verify your site has a [safe browsing status](https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?hl=en).
2. Report an [incorrect phishing warning](https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en).
3. Register your site in [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/).

Best,