# Getting data breach warning in chrome when logging in a web app I deployed on heroku

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, mern

I was getting a data breach warning message in chrome in development mode whenever I logged in in a MERN web app I developed. I thought the warning would go away in production, but after I deployed it in Heroku, I still get the warning message, and that I need to change my password. My question is: what does exactly this warning mean? Is there something wrong in my code that is not secure, or I can ignore it?

Comment: This is a Google Chrome feature. It informs you if the username/password combination you type in has been breached in any data leaks. This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769206/a-data-breach-on-a-site-or-app-exposed-your-password-chrome-recommends-changing "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769206/a-data-breach-on-a-site-or-app-exposed-your-password-chrome-recommends-changing").